# Google Cloud Speech Using Java

Tags: java, google-speech-api

I am trying to communicate with Google Cloud Speech API from my Java program, but I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid Wav File: Not 16 bit Linear PCM or 8 bit MULAW.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Do what the error message said. Send a wav file using 16bit Linear PCM oder 8 bit MULAW. Your wave file has the wrong encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply Rene M. how to convert my file to 16bit linear PCM ?. please suggest some solution

Comment: I have a running VoIP solution, developed in Java. where I have to convert alot of sound recording. To do this i use "sox" a command line audio converter tool. http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Updated formatting so the error is highlighted

Answer (score 4):

The google cloud speech API accept wav files. And not only.
From the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding

> Note: Speech-to-Text supports **WAV** files with LINEAR16 or MULAW
>   encoded audio.

According to the speech-to-text/ resource on the cloud web site of google speech to text, i was able to upload .wav file with 8 bit PCM SIGNED. The transcription was fine. However if i try to upload the file using their Java API, it gives this error. I tested several libraries, including the new beta. So i can agree its strange. I can play 8 bit 16KHz PCM SIGNED encoding on every player and also 8KHz and there is nothing wrong with the header of the file, i can upload it, but not via the Java API.

Here are some tips that may help:
If you want to use the API, you must convert to 16 bit PCM, or 8 bit ULAW for example.

For that purpose you can use **javax.sound.sampled** library.

Take a look at this example: [SimpleSoundCapture](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Thisisasimpleprogramtorecordsoundsandplaythemback.htm/)!
You can modify for your needs. Feed the "out" variable ByteArrayOutputStream or record custom encoding wav file with ULAW encoding.

You can use this settings:

```
AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.ULAW; 
floatrate = 16000.0f; 
int channels = 1; 
int frameSize = 4; 
int sampleSize = 8; 
boolean bigEndian = true;
```

Google was able to recognize ULAW sample without a problem from the 2nd, 3th time. Sometimes even from the first. Tested with 8000.0f too. 
Before using ULAW, remove the setEncoding() method from the RecognitionConfig object of the speach API, because using ULAW may cause another exception.

```
 RecognitionConfig config
                = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                //      .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.UNRECOGNIZED)
                .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google cloud speech API does not accept .wav files. You'll have to convert your current wav file to a headerless linear16 uncompressed file (using something like Audacity, for instance)

Also, if you're using a local file it can't be longer than one minute. Longer files need to be uploaded to a Google cloud storage bucket first.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply Frauke Nonnenmacher. actually am recording my voice and converting into file then am uploading to google cloud speech. as you said my file is lesser than one minute only. and i have tried with other format files such as .flac and .raw also. for that also same issue is coming. can you suggest me any solution to solve this

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that your audio file has no header and is a 16-bit linear PCM file, then I can't really tell with the information you've given. Is the code you're using the sample code from Google? (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech)

Comment: To test whether or not it's an issue with the audio file, try the "audio.raw" file from the Google sample project here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api/resources

Comment: hi  Frauke Nonnenmacher, yes am using sample code from google only. as you suggested i have tried that audio.raw file also. when ever am using audio.raw file as input it is not giving output simply running the program. there is no results.

Comment: i have tried with another one wav file, for that it is not giving that error but unfortunately there is no result also

Comment: In this case, since you're no longer getting the problem you described in your question here, I suggest you start another question for your new problem. When you ask, make sure you include the code where it's going wrong, what you were expecting to happen, what's actually happening, and everything you have tried to solve the problem yourself. If you don't do that, your question will likely be downvoted.

Comment: SyncRecognizeResponse response = speech.syncRecognize(config, audio); System.out.println("response: "+response); In this line i have tried to print response but it is empty (Note: Invalid Wav File: exception not coming)

Comment: Please start another question where you can post a sufficient amount of code for others to recreate the problem. The code you provided just now is completely insufficient for anybody to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok frauke nonnenmacher thanks for your suggestion. i will create another post